# How to force a Func as strongly typed dependency injection in .net core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection, func

I expose in a library all the mechanism to deal with a message broker, the client needs to use an extension method to use it where I require it to supply of a collection of handlers implementing `IMessageHandler` interface that will deal with each subscribe channel.
It works, but my prototype only require dependency injection through a `Func` that I would like to be strongly typed, to force the client to supply the expected interface dependency injection.

Here is the interface for message handling :

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void HandleMessageAsync(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
}
```

And the prototype of my extension method in the lib :

```
public static IServiceCollection UseTheSuperMessageBroker(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration config,
    params Func<IServiceCollection>[] handlers)
```

The client can then use the extension method like this :

```
services.UseTheSuperMessageBroker(Configuration,
handlers: new Func<IServiceCollection>[] {
    () => services.AddSingleton<IMessageHandler, myMessageHandler1>(),
    () => services.AddSingleton<IMessageHandler, myMessageHandler2>()
});
```

But nothing prevent the client to supply any dependency injection not related with the `IMessageHandler` interface, indeed the last parameter let us do this :

```
services.UseTheSuperMessageBroker(
    Configuration,
    handlers: new Func<IServiceCollection>[] {
        () => services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(),
        () => services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMongoRepository<>), typeof(MongoRepository<>))
    });
```

**This is compiling but not expected.**

So is there any mechanism I could use to force the `Func` to use dependency injection related to `IMessageHandler` interface only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no way to stop that, because you're just using `IServiceCollection` directly. In fact, this code here isn't even using lambda locals, but rather the locals of the containing method, i.e. `services`. Essentially, *anything* can be done here, as long as the means exists in `ConfigureServices` to do so.

It would be far better, if this is your requirement, to simply take a collection of `IMessageHandler` types and then register those in the method, rather than using a collection of  `Func`.

```
public static IServiceCollection UseTheSuperMessageBroker(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration config,
    params Type[] handlers)

services.UseTheSuperMessageBroker(Configuration,
    handlers: new[] {
        typeof(myMessageHandler1),
        typeof(myMessageHandler2)
    });
```

Then, inside that method:

```
foreach (var handler in handlers)
{
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMessageHandler), handler);
}
```

That won't technically stop them from adding types that do not implement `IMessageHandler`, but because you're binding to `IMessageHandler` explicitly, it will fail if they do so.

Comment: Indeed I started this way, but because the type are by definition not class, I can't be sure it's a IMessageHandler that is passed on run not at build

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT :

I fact it easily can be "hacked", but I can't understand why we are able to do that ?
Here I remove the `IMessageHandler` interface requirement for the `TService` generic parameter, so I'm able to use any interface with it's implementation.

```
public class DelegateHandler
{
    public delegate void MyMessagebrokerDelegateHandler<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection services) 
        where TService : class, IMessageHandler
        where TImplementation : class, TService, new();

public static void MyMessagebrokerHandlerSupplier<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection services)
    where TService : class //, IMessageHandler <== REMOVED !!!
    where TImplementation : class, TService, new()
{
    services.AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>();
}
```

}

So I'm able to do :

```
  services.UseTheSuperMessageBroker(Configuration,
  handlers: new MyMessagebrokerDelegateHandler<IMessageHandler, BaseMessageHandler>[] {
                MyMessagebrokerHandlerSupplier<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>, // <== HACKED !
                MyMessagebrokerHandlerSupplier<IMessageHandler, myMessageHandler2>
            });
```

But WHY am I able to use a promise that doesn't respect the delegate prototype ?
The `TService : class, IMessageHandler` in delegate and `TService : where TService : class` in the static method ??

### Original post :

I finally found a solution based on `generic delegates`, I don't know if the same thing could be done with `Func` as well.
Here is my new extension method :

```
        public static IServiceCollection UseTheSuperMessageBroker<TService, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config,  params MyMessagebrokerDelegateHandler<TService, TImplementation>[] handlers)
        where TService : class, IMessageHandler
        where TImplementation : class, TService, new()
       {
          handlers.ToList().ForEach(h =>
          {
            // Resolve the promise
            h.Invoke(services);
          });
        ...
```

My generic handler :

```
public class DelegateHandler
{
    public delegate void MyMessagebrokerDelegateHandler<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection services) 
        where TService : class, IMessageHandler
        where TImplementation : class, TService, new();

    public static void MyMessagebrokerHandlerSupplier<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection services)
        where TService : class, IMessageHandler
        where TImplementation : class, TService, new()
    {
        services.AddSingleton<TService, TImplementation>();
    }
}
```

The base class, only used for the client declaration (**did you know any way to get rid of this ?**)

```
public sealed class BaseMessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    public Subscribers _sub { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public void HandleMessageAsync(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And finally the client call :

```
      services.UseTheSuperMessageBroker(Configuration,
      handlers: new MyMessagebrokerDelegateHandler<IMessageHandler, BaseMessageHandler>[] {
                    MyMessagebrokerHandlerSupplier<IMessageHandler, myMessageHandler1>,
                    MyMessagebrokerHandlerSupplier<IMessageHandler, myMessageHandler2>
                });
```

It works like a charm!